# SSIS schema switching deadlocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package which takes data that has changed in the last 1/2 hour and transfers it from a DB2 database into a SQL server.  This data is loaded into an empty import table (import.tablename) then inserted into a staging table (newlive.tablename).   The staging table is then schema switched with the live (dbo) table within a transaction.  FYI, the dbo tables are the backend to a visualization tool (Looker)

My problem is that the schema switching is now creating deadlocks.  Everytime I run the package, it affects different tables.  I've been using this process with larger tables before (also backend to Looker) and have not had this problem before.

I read in another post that the user was having a similar problem because of indexes but all the data has been written to the destination tables.

Any ideas or suggestion of where to look would be much appreciated

The [schema switching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) code is within a Execute SQL Task in the SSIS Package with:

```
BEGIN TRAN 
ALTER SCHEMA LAST_LIVE TRANSFER DBO.TABLENAME 
ALTER SCHEMA DBO TRANSFER NEW_LIVE.TABLENAME 
GRANT SELECT ON DBO.TABLENAME TO LOOKER_LOOKUP 
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: @bilinkc I updated the schema switching code in the main post

Comment: My assumption is that the deadlock happens on the first statement - trying to switch the table from dbo to last_live gets blocked by reader activity from the Looker tool. A quick way to test that would be to add `REVOKE SELECT on DBO.TABLENAME TO LOOKER_LOOKUP;` before your transaction. That way the alter schema should be able to get an exclusive lock on the table for the moments it needs to do the switch.

Comment: Might be interesting to see if a partition switch would run into the same challenges. Suspect it would but don't know that. `ALTER TABLE dbo.TABLENAME SWITCH TO NEW_LIVE.TABLENAME;`

Comment: @bilinkc Thanks.  I'll try you're idea on the revoke to test but any ideas why it happens on different tables and not the same ones.  Also, this is running in a dev environment with no other user but myself so it's odd that the dbo would be accessed at all since I'm not running any queries from the Looker tool.

Comment: Oh, if it's quiet then you'd need to look at the deadlock graph to find out what other process has its finger on the table preventing you from getting an exclusive lock.

Comment: So it looks like it's a metadata lock on multiple different tables doing schema switching. All the tables are completely independent (no FK).  So as the data is loaded into each table, the schema is switched for that table.  Could the deadlock occur because I'm schema switching multiple tables at the same time.  What are the potential pitfalls if I remove the transaction ?  Or can I set the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL on each separate Execute SQL Task for the schema switching?